# Float image centered above 2 divs

Tags: html, css

I'm trying the achieve the following setup for a page, where there is a left and right div and a 'floating' image in the center above the two divs:

[image: Floating image]

I've tried giving the img1 a `z-index` and a `position: relative` (or `position: absolute` for that matter) but that didn't help achieve my goal. Any takes on how to float an image above these two divs, centered?

I'm using the following pieces of code currently:

CSS http://pastebin.com/4uLHwkXt

HTML http://pastebin.com/t6yCTR0r

Comment: Can you post your HTML & CSS code so we can see what the current page looks like? It's easier to provide an answer that way.

Comment: Added the code @DanielJames

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the **shortest code necessary** to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Edit your question to include the code as a snippet or in a code-block instead of an external link, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign `position: relative;` to DIV1 and the following settings to .IMG1. .IMG1 has to be *inside*  DIV1 (i.e. be a child of DIV1) for this to work.

```
.IMG1 {
  position:absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 30px; /* adjust as needed */
  transform: translateX(+50%);
}
```

addition: You hadn't posted your code before, so I just described the basic necessary settings with the element names from your graphic description, but that should be clear enogh.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code: You can adjust the div widths and margins according to your requirement. This code also adjust according to the desktop screen.
Thanks

CSS:

```
.floatedDiv{
  float:left;
  width:50%;
  background:grey;
  height:50px;
}
.imgDiv {
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
position: absolute;
background: green;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -10px; /*half of the length of the div*/
top:15px;
}
.red{
background:red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body style='margin:0px;'>
    <div class='floatedDiv red'></div>
    <div class='floatedDiv'></div>
    <div class='imgDiv'></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I [position:absolute](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_position_absolute) the image and add **position:relative** to the parent div.

**HTML (with bootstrap)**

```css
.col-6{ height:500px; }
img{
  margin-left:33%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row" style="position:relative;">
  <div class="col-6 bg-success"></div>
  <div class="col-6 bg-warning"></div>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/150?grayscale" style="position:absolute;">
</div>
```